# What is the meaning for this Specific Random Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, random

I've been studying a script that uses the random function in MATLAB.

```
x = rand(2,4) > 5
```

Explanatory - a random function generates random numbers.

But what I don't understand is the purpose of the

```
> 5
```

part.

The output is a 2-by-4 logical array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand(2,4)` will return a 2x4 array of random numbers between 0 and 1. The `> 5` will return 1 for those numbers larger than 5 and 0 for those less than or equal to 5. So `rand(2,4) > 5` will always give 2x4 array of zeros.

If you were to e.g. do `rand(2,4) > 0.4` then approximately 40% of the elements in the obtained array will be 1 and approximately 60% of the elements will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

function rand(i) produces random numbers between 0 to 1 in the dimensions you want
so this code will produce a 2x4 array which all of its numbers are lower than 1 so all of them are lower than 5 , therefor the output will be a 2x4 of zeros